# Calling Web Service Function returns a string[] from Windows Phone

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8, sql-server-2012

I have a web service and a method that returns a list of string. When I call it in my Windows Phone app and I put it in a ListBox, the result is **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader**. I am new in web services and I don`t know if the problem is from web service or from windors phone.
here is my code:

Method from web service:

```
    public string [] GetActions(string cnp)
    {
        string[] lista = new string[300];
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Denumire from Actiuni where cnp='"+cnp+"'", con);

            SqlDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int k = 0;
            while (re.Read())
            {
                lista[k++] = re.ToString();

            }
            re.Close();

        }
        catch (SqlException exception)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }


        return lista;
    }
```

And here is my Windows Phone code:

```
public void DesplayActions()
    {

        ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
        client.GetActionsCompleted += client_ValidareActiuniCompleted;
        client.GetActionsAsync(cnp);

    }



    void client_GetActionsCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetActionsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {


        for(int i=0;i<e.Result.Count;i++)
            Listbox1.Items.Add(e.Result[i]);


    }



    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DesplayActions();

    }
```

Comment: Please add some more details - it is unclear what is the problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lista[k++] = re.ToString();
```

is where you've done wrong. You've called ToString on the datareader.

You want to do this:

```
lista[k++]  = rdr.GetString(0);
```

0 means the first column in the resultset, as a string. Google the SqlDataReader class for more information, or to select a column by name rather than index.

Answer (score 0):

Thx. That work now in the web service. But not works in the WF app. I thik is the same problem with ListBox but I don`t know the syntax for that. It nod like in WFA where I declare a ListViewItem and after that I add subitems.